# How to "Merge" a Mesh

Tags: mesh, geometry

So I have a mesh I downloaded, but it intersects itself. I would like it to be one large single shell instead of having various intersection areas. Like the edges would go through faces. The model isn't multiple objects but one large intersecting shape. Is there a way to make it so it becomes one large shell? 3D Builder, a program which comes with windows, has an option called Merge, but it does a really messy job with it and so I would like something like that in blender.
[image: Shape]

Comment: have you tried using the boolean tool in edit mode?

Comment: yea but for this model, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to separate each shell into its own object, and then boolean all the objects together.

To do this quickly:

- Select everything in Edit Mode
- `P` > Separate by Loose Parts
- Enable the Bool Tool add-on (included with blender by default)
- Select all the objects in Object Mode
- Click the Auto Boolean > Union button in the Bool Tool panel:

[image: auto union]

You may want to triangulate the mesh in edit mode (`Ctrl`-`T`) afterward to make more sense of it.

Comment: Unfortunately my object doesn't have any loose parts, it's all connected. If you select it's faces and continue to select it's adjacent faces, it continues until every face of the mesh gets selected

Comment: Can you upload the blend?

Comment: Here's the download link: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1CdiavXETxW39oDwudrII0ahQe2zdE4MY

Comment: That is the strangest mesh I've ever seen in my life. It isn't even a solid object (which is the first step for reliable boolean operations), you can press Ctrl-Alt-Shift-M to select non-manifold edges and see.